# Better to have a field "City" or a table "City"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I'm making a website with Ruby on Rails and I'm thinking of the database structure.

The website is very simple, we make a list of many places, and tell from which city they are.

For example "Tour Eiffel" / Paris
Or "Empire State Building" / New York

For the database, which choice seems the best for you ?

Having a field "City" in the table "places" or making a table "cities", with a join table to connect it to the table places ?

We are going to have many places and make a page for each city. I think making the join table offers much flexibility and allows us to use less space at the end on the Database but I'm not sure.

Thank you

Comment: There is such a thing as "too" normalized, but with everything you've described above it makes sense to have two tables

Answer (score 2):

Having a "city" table and a "places" table is definitely the way to go. For more information, look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 1):

Normalization - 
Avoid repeating the same data within a table or tables.
There's so many places in a single city. When it comes to search places in one city this will help a lot.
Also your project can grow a lot and you might need to and city to another table like people's, restaurants, and so on.
So yes, two tables is the way.
Good look with your project.